# Multiple GraphView scroll

Tags: android-graphview

I have to place few separate live charts in Activity, that will have  a common X axis. I want to implement the next functionality: when I scroll one of the charts the other will be scrolled too.
How can I implement this ?
Thanks a lot, and excuse me for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you have to modify a little bit the source code of graphview.

take a look into the touch listener and at this point you can call set viewport of the other graphs.

https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/com/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView.java#L149